# Can you project on an orthogonal basis for a multipartite quantum system using only local operations and classical communication?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-measurements, quantum-teleportation

Say Alice possesses one qubit, and Bob two, and that the joint state is $|\psi_{A, B_1, B_2}\rangle = \alpha|n_1\rangle + \beta |n_2\rangle$, where $|n_1\rangle$ and $|n_2\rangle$ are orthonormal basis states for the combined Hilbert space. If you have access to all qubits, there obviously is a measurement which projects on the basis that includes $|n_1\rangle$ and $|n_2\rangle$.

However, what if you only allow Alice and Bob to do local measurements on their qubits? Then, I assume that Bob would need to send at least one classical bit to Alice for a joint measurement to be possible. Do they also need local quantum registers? Can we say anything about when such a joint measurement is possible?

Perhaps a concrete example would be: Let's say Alice and Bob share the state $|\psi_{A, B_1, B_2}\rangle = \alpha|n_1\rangle + \beta |n_2\rangle$. Is it possible, using only LOCC, to end up in the joint state $|n_1\rangle$ with probability $|\alpha|^2$, and in $|n_2\rangle$ with probability $|\beta|^2$, so that afterwards both parties know what the shared state is?

I assume that the precise implementation of such a measurement will depend on the states $|n_1\rangle$ and $|n_2\rangle$, but is there a general rule for when such a joint measurement is possible?

---

Crossposted to qc.se: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/34323/can-you-project-on-an-orthogonal-basis-for-a-multipartite-system-using-only-loca

Comment: What is the measurement you would like to implement? Do you want a projective measurement with outcomes |n1>, |n2>, and something orthogonal to it? Do you just want to be able to distinguish |n1> from |n2>? Should the measurement only work on the state you write, or in a general setting? Do you care about the post-measurement state? You need to be more specific.

Comment: My apologies, the phrasing was indeed confusing. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Is the "concrete example" what you really want? Because otherwise, it is still quite unclear. Maybe you just dump the general part and stick to the "concrete example"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this (the concrete example) is impossible.

Take, for instance,
$$
|\psi\rangle = \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} |n_1\rangle + \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|n_2\rangle \ ,
$$
with $|n_{1,2}\rangle = \tfrac1{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle \pm |11\rangle)$.

Then, $|\psi\rangle$ is unentangled, so there is no way to end up with an entangled state $|n_i\rangle$ using LOCC.

Comment: Ok, yes that is a very good and simple counterexample. Thanks!

Comment: @Abelaer My feeling is the nature of the example rather points to a weakness in your question: E.g., if I just change the phases of the two states, the situation might change drastically, so it is highly sensitive to the decomposition you choose. Also, it is not a property of the state alone, or of n1 and n2 alone ...

Comment: I am interested in doing this for some specific orthonormal states, and was hoping that there was a guarantee that such joint measurements always existed. I now see that they clearly don’t, so that I will have to come up with a specific way to exploit the structure of n1 and n2. There’s still hope, as the superposition I work with is already entangled, but it’s going to take some work then. Thanks for your help!